# boundary conditions of a diffusion-reaction system

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

The central question is: Is my problem wrong or badly formulated?

**Problem**

I have to calculate the steady state concentration of a molecule $c$ given by the PDE

$0 = D\cdot\Delta_r c - a\cdot c$

The parameter $a$ describes the exponential decay of the molecule. For reasons of symmetry, the concentration only depends on the distance to the cell center (r).

The boundaries (in spherical coordinate system) of the system are given by:

1. A cell at the center of the coordinate system and the cell surface at r = R and $c$ is consumed at the cell surface. The boundary condition for this is a Neumann BC with a constant flux $j$:
   $\left.\frac{d}{dr}c \right|_{r=R} = \frac{j}{D}$
2. The second boundary acts like an inexhaustible reservoir of molecules that is also not exhausted by the consumption on cell surfaces or by decay. For large distances from the cell center, the molecule concentration is constant:
   $c(r\rightarrow\infty) + \left.\frac{d}{dr}c \right|_{r\rightarrow\infty} = c_\infty$.

Is there a solution for c(r) with the given boundary conditions?

---

**What I've done so far...**

The general solution of the PDE is given by:

$c(r) = \frac{k_1e^{\sqrt{a/D}\cdot r}}{r} + \frac{k_2e^{-\sqrt{a/D}\cdot r}}{r}$

and we have to set $k_1 = 0$ since $lim_{r\rightarrow \infty}c(r) = \infty$.

Thus I have still both boundary conditions to determine $k_2$. Using the first boundary condition I determine $k_2$. The solution is given by

$c(r) = \frac{R^2 \cdot j}{D + R\sqrt{D\cdot a}} \frac{e^{-\sqrt{a/D}\cdot (r - R)}}{r}$

$c(r)$ is completely determined but  $lim_{r\rightarrow \infty}c(r) = 0$ and does not satisfy 2. boundary condition.
Where is the problem???

**Alternative Approach**

From the ODE

$\dot{c} = 0 = A - a\cdot c$

with the constant influx $A$ I know that I need a influx to obtain a steady state of c, which is non-zero. Thus I modified the PDE to

$0 = D\cdot\Delta_r c - a\cdot c + A$

With this additional influx, the resulting solution is given by

$c(r) = \frac{R^2 \cdot j}{D + R\sqrt{D\cdot a}} \frac{e^{-\sqrt{a/D}\cdot (r - R)}}{r} + \frac{A}{a}$

and the term $\frac{A}{a} = c_\infty$ causes the match with the second boundary condition. **BUT** now there is a constant influx $A$ of molecules everywhere in the system that does not exist in the formulation of my problem.